# Induction (concerning $1+z+\dots+z^n$) and follow up question

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, induction

I am doing a review of stuff from earlier in the semester and I can't prove this by induction:

> Use induction on $n$ to verify that $1+x+\cdots+z^n= \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$ (for $z\not=1)$. Use this to show that if $c$ is an $n$-th root of $1$ and $c\not=1$, then $1+c+\cdots+c^n=0$.

There is also a follow up question based on that one:

> Show that if $c$ is any $n$-th root of $1$ and $c\not=1$ then
>   $$1+c+c^2+\cdots+c^{n-1}=0$$

Note: If memory serves me correctly there is a misprint in one of these questions. I can't remember which one.

Comment: Well, take $n=2$ - do you know any 2nd root of unity, other than 1? Can you then check to see which equation holds? That should find you the misprint.

Comment: ...hmmm........ok, I see now that the misprint is in question 1. Cheers. What about the proof by induction, I cant get it to work out.

Comment: Why don't you write out what you've done? It will be easier for someone to help you if we know where you got stuck or went off the rails.

Comment: Ha. Within 2 minutes of my last comment, three people posted complete proofs. So much for pedagogy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I started writing my answer before your 2nd comment. I've deleted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction: $n=1$ is true $1+z={(1-z)(1+z) \over (1-z)}={1-z^2 \over 1-z}$, induction step $n\Rightarrow n+1$
$$
1+z+\dots+z^n+z^{n+1}={1-z^{n+1}\over 1-z} + z^{n+1}
={1-z^{n+1}\over 1-z} + {(1-z)z^{n+1}\over(1-z)} = {1-z^{n+1}+z^{n+1}-z^{n+2}\over 1-z}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For the induction, it is true for $n=0:\ 1=\frac{1-z}{1-z}$.  Now assume $\sum_{i=0}^k z^i=\frac {1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}$.  Then $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} z^i=\frac {1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}+z^{k+1}=\frac {1-z^{k+1}+z^{k+1}-z^{k+2}}{1-z}=\frac {1-z^{k+2}}{1-z}$